# Capture all keywords from string with brackets rails

Tags: ruby

I want to capture all occurrence of keywords from below string in hash.

```
str = "Coming this week for [CurrentCourseName] chapter [Chaptername] of interesting event [EventName]"
```

**Required Output:**

```
["CurrentCourseName", "Chaptername", "EventName"]
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Your requ[i]red out is not valid ruby.

Comment: I edited the question - presumably he's wanting an array.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the full power of Ruby on Rails and not just Ruby?

Comment: Note that I also changed the tag to just "ruby".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `scan` method with a regular expression:

```
str.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/).flatten
```

Actual output:

```
2.2-head :001 > str = "Coming this week for [CurrentCourseName] chapter [Chaptername] of interesting event [EventName]"
 => "Coming this week for [CurrentCourseName] chapter [Chaptername] of interesting event [EventName]" 
2.2-head :002 > str.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/).flatten
 => ["CurrentCourseName", "Chaptername", "EventName"]
```

Comment: Or you can use a lookahead and a lookbehind `str.scan(/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/)` to avoid using `flatten`.